# i used sub-domain for my vendor registration page in WordPress but admin-ajax.php not found

Tags: wordpress

My domain is tenspark.com. when a user signs up with this link  https://tenspark.com/wholesaler/ . there is no issue. But if a user signs up with my subdomain link https://wholesaler.tenspark.com/ I have an issue with my admin-ajax.php file is not found.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the javascript function having hard coded domain name (https://tenspark.com/) instead of having a dynamic one. (see the screenshot below of view-source for https://whoesaler.tenspark.com/)

[image]

**Solution:**

Either change the url for admin-ajax.php to your subdomain one manually, or else make this code dynamic to adapt to any domain you're calling it in by using:

```
<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanx for reply but my question is my all file on https://tenspark.com/ and on the 
 subdomain https://whoesaler.tenspark.com/ i used only onepage page so how to call admin-ajax.php for my subdomain.

Comment: you can not have a cross domain ajax request, one thing that can be done is that you can use your own ajax function to work as proxy and forward the data to the other domain in backend imho